# Get the body of the clicked page in order to add html element

Tags: javascript

```js
function createMyNavBar(body) {
  const attrNavBar = {
    style: `
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    `
  };
  const navContainer = document.createElement("div");
  setAttributes(navContainer, attrNavBar);

  const attrP = {
    style: `
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    `
  };
  const p = document.createElement("p");
  p.textContent = "nav bar";
  setAttributes(p, attrP);

  navContainer.appendChild(p);
  body.appendChild(navContainer);
}

function setAttributes(element, attributes) {
  Object.keys(attributes).forEach((attr) => {
    element.setAttribute(attr, attributes[attr]);
  });
}

const body = document.body;
createMyNavBar(body);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#idDiv {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="idDiv">
      <p>HOME PAGE</p>
      <a id="id1" href="page/page1.html"> page 1 </a> <br />
      <a id="id2" href="page/page2.html"> page 2 </a>
    </div>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I created a navbar (navContainer) in javascript. I would like to inject the nav bar into every html page where the user will click on an . Each of the html pages is stored in a folder inside my project. I created a createMyNavBar function which takes the `document.querySelector("body")` element as an argument, then I inject my navigation code with `body.appendChild(navContainer)`;
The navigation will allow me to go to the next page or the previous page
My question is how i can get the body of the clicked page ?

[codeSandBox nav bar](https://codesandbox.io/s/nav-bar-7st6s6?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Can you please paste the relevant code in your question rather than just posting a link?

Comment: It would be more effective to use server-side rendering on whatever platform you're using. Failing that use the fetch api to get the html for each page then inject it into a container div in the html. The third option would be to add the javascript on every page but this is best solved using server-side rendering imho